# Construct the regular representation of Z3 and diagonalize it

Tags: group-theory

Explicitly construct the regular representation of $\mathbb Z_3$ and diagonalize it. Since we are now fully diagonal every entry must furnish a one dimensional irreducible representation. Do you think you recovered all the irreps we have found in class?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Yes , you will. The regular representation contains at least once all the irreducible representations of a finite group (in good characteristic).

Comment: How would we know what irreps you found in class?

Comment: @anomaly I guess they found the one-dimensional ones.

Answer (score 2):

The regular representation of $\mathbb Z_3$ is 
$$\begin{align}0 &\mapsto \left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right),\;\; \\
1 &\mapsto \left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right), \\
2 &\mapsto \left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right).
\end{align}$$
Its diagonal form is
$$n \mapsto \left( \begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & e^{2\pi n / 3} & 0\\
0 & 0 &e^{-2\pi n / 3}
\end{matrix} \right).$$
Do you see why?